# Remove everything behind "-" with Regex in Atom

Tags: regex, search, replace, atom-editor

How can I Remove everything behind the "-" with regex in Atom.

**I have a list with**

- Alex Tweewielers - 's Gravenzande
- Nijland Tweewielers BV - 's Heerenberg
- Tweewielercentrum - 's-Gravendeel
- Leo Joosse Tweewielers BV - Aagtekerke

**Result should be**

- Alex Tweewielers
- Nijland Tweewielers BV
- Tweewielercentrum
- Leo Joosse Tweewielers BV

Comment: `How can I Remove everything behind the "-" ` ... your results imply that you want to _keep_ everything behind the dash.

Answer (score 0):

**Find:**

```
^(.*?)\s-.*$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

In the event that you have more than one dash (preceded by a whitespace) in a given line, this solution would discard everything after the first dash.